# sum of new total after categories are disabled in D3.js Donut Chart

Tags: d3.js, donut-chart

I have a donut chart that recalculates the percentages and sizes of each category when a label/category is disabled in the legend. What I would like to do is recalculate the total count excluding the disabled categories. I'd like to do this everytime a user enables or disables a category in the legend.

Code below:

```js
// define data
var dataset = [
    {label: "Venue", count: 16107},
    {label: "Photographer", count: 2783},
    {label: "Wedding/Event Planner", count: 2037},
    {label: "Reception Band", count: 4156},
    {label: "Reception DJ", count: 1245},
    {label: "Florist/Decor", count: 2534},
    {label: "Videographer", count: 1995},
    {label: "Wedding Dress", count: 1564},
    {label: "Groom's Attire", count: 280},
    {label: "Wedding Cake", count: 582},
    {label: "Ceremony Site", count: 2197},
    {label: "Ceremony Musicians", count: 755},
    {label: "Invitations", count: 2534},
    {label: "Transportation", count: 1995},
    {label: "Favors", count: 1564},
    {label: "Rehearsal Dinner", count: 280},
    {label: "Engagement Ring", count: 582},
    {label: "Officiant", count: 2197}
  ];

// chart dimensions
var width = 800;
var height = 800;

// a circle chart needs a radius
var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
var donutWidth = 100; // size of donut hole. not needed if doing pie chart

// legend dimensions
var legendRectSize = 25; // defines the size of the colored squares in legend
var legendSpacing = 6; // defines spacing between squares

// define color scale
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20b);
// more color scales: https://bl.ocks.org/pstuffa/3393ff2711a53975040077b7453781a9

// calculate new total
var total = d3.sum(dataset, d => d.count);

// define new total section
var newTotal = d3.select('new-total-holder')
  .append('span')
  .attr('class', 'newTotal')

var svg = d3.select('#chart') // select element in the DOM with id 'chart'
  .append('svg') // append an svg element to the element we've selected
  .attr('width', width) // set the width of the svg element we just added
  .attr('height', height) // set the height of the svg element we just added
  .append('g') // append 'g' element to the svg element
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2) + ',' + (height / 2) + ')'); // our reference is now to the 'g' element. centerting the 'g' element to the svg element

var arc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius - donutWidth) // radius - donutWidth = size of donut hole. use 0 for pie chart
  .outerRadius(radius); // size of overall chart

var pie = d3.pie() // start and end angles of the segments
  .value(function(d) { return d.count; }) // how to extract the numerical data from each entry in our dataset
  .sort(null); // by default, data sorts in oescending value. this will mess with our animation so we set it to null

// define tooltip
var tooltip = d3.select('#chart') // select element in the DOM with id 'chart'
  .append('div') // append a div element to the element we've selected                                    
  .attr('class', 'tooltip'); // add class 'tooltip' on the divs we just selected

tooltip.append('div') // add divs to the tooltip defined above                            
  .attr('class', 'label'); // add class 'label' on the selection                         

tooltip.append('div') // add divs to the tooltip defined above                     
  .attr('class', 'count'); // add class 'count' on the selection                  

tooltip.append('div') // add divs to the tooltip defined above  
  .attr('class', 'percent'); // add class 'percent' on the selection

// Confused? see below:

// <div id="chart">
//   <div class="tooltip">
//     <div class="label">
//     </div>
//     <div class="count">
//     </div>
//     <div class="percent">
//     </div>
//   </div>
// </div>

dataset.forEach(function(d) {
  d.count = +d.count; // calculate count as we iterate through the data
  d.enabled = true; // add enabled property to track which entries are checked
});

// creating the chart
var path = svg.selectAll('path') // select all path elements inside the svg. specifically the 'g' element. they don't exist yet but they will be created below
  .data(pie(dataset)) //associate dataset wit he path elements we're about to create. must pass through the pie function. it magically knows how to extract values and bakes it into the pie
  .enter() //creates placeholder nodes for each of the values
  .append('path') // replace placeholders with path elements
  .attr('d', arc) // define d attribute with arc function above
  .attr('fill', function(d) { return color(d.data.label); }) // use color scale to define fill of each label in dataset
  .each(function(d) { this._current - d; }); // creates a smooth animation for each track

// mouse event handlers are attached to path so they need to come after its definition
path.on('mouseover', function(d) {  // when mouse enters div      
 var total = d3.sum(dataset.map(function(d) { // calculate the total number of tickets in the dataset         
  return (d.enabled) ? d.count : 0; // checking to see if the entry is enabled. if it isn't, we return 0 and cause other percentages to increase                                      
  }));                                                      
 var percent = Math.round(1000 * d.data.count / total) / 10; // calculate percent
 tooltip.select('.label').html(d.data.label); // set current label           
 tooltip.select('.count').html('$' + d.data.count); // set current count            
 tooltip.select('.percent').html(percent + '%'); // set percent calculated above          
 tooltip.style('display', 'block'); // set display                     
});                                                           

path.on('mouseout', function() { // when mouse leaves div                        
  tooltip.style('display', 'none'); // hide tooltip for that element
 });

path.on('mousemove', function(d) { // when mouse moves                  
  tooltip.style('top', (d3.event.layerY + 10) + 'px') // always 10px below the cursor
    .style('left', (d3.event.layerX + 10) + 'px'); // always 10px to the right of the mouse
  });

// define legend
var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend') // selecting elements with class 'legend'
  .data(color.domain()) // refers to an array of labels from our dataset
  .enter() // creates placeholder
  .append('g') // replace placeholders with g elements
  .attr('class', 'legend') // each g is given a legend class
  .attr('transform', function(d, i) {                   
    var height = legendRectSize + legendSpacing; // height of element is the height of the colored square plus the spacing      
    var offset =  height * color.domain().length / 2; // vertical offset of the entire legend = height of a single element & half the total number of elements  
    var horz = -2 * legendRectSize; // the legend is shifted to the left to make room for the text
    var vert = i * height - offset; // the top of the element is hifted up or down from the center using the offset defiend earlier and the index of the current element 'i'               
      return 'translate(' + horz + ',' + vert + ')'; //return translation       
   });

// adding colored squares to legend
legend.append('rect') // append rectangle squares to legend                                   
  .attr('width', legendRectSize) // width of rect size is defined above                        
  .attr('height', legendRectSize) // height of rect size is defined above                      
  .style('fill', color) // each fill is passed a color
  .style('stroke', color) // each stroke is passed a color
  .on('click', function(label) {
    var rect = d3.select(this); // this refers to the colored squared just clicked
    var enabled = true; // set enabled true to default
    var totalEnabled = d3.sum(dataset.map(function(d) { // can't disable all options
      return (d.enabled) ? 1 : 0; // return 1 for each enabled entry. and summing it up
    }));
    if (rect.attr('class') === 'disabled') { // if class is disabled
      rect.attr('class', ''); // remove class disabled
    } else { // else
      if (totalEnabled < 2) return; // if less than two labels are flagged, exit
      rect.attr('class', 'disabled'); // otherwise flag the square disabled
      enabled = false; // set enabled to false
    }

    pie.value(function(d) { 
      if (d.label === label) d.enabled = enabled; // if entry label matches legend label
        return (d.enabled) ? d.count : 0; // update enabled property and return count or 0 based on the entry's status
    });

    path = path.data(pie(dataset)); // update pie with new data

    path.transition() // transition of redrawn pie
      .duration(750) // 
      .attrTween('d', function(d) { // 'd' specifies the d attribute that we'll be animating
        var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d); // this = current path element
        this._current = interpolate(0); // interpolate between current value and the new value of 'd'
        return function(t) {
          return arc(interpolate(t));
        };
      });
    
    // calculate new total
    var newTotalCalc = d3.sum(dataset, d => d.count)
    console.log(newTotalCalc);
  
    // append newTotalCalc to newTotal which is defined above
    newTotal.append("text")
      .text(newTotalCalc);
  });

// adding text to legend
legend.append('text')                                    
  .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
  .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
  .text(function(d) { return d; }); // return label
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
}
.title-holder {
  text-align: center;
}
.title {
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}
.font {
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* legend */
.legend {
  font-size: 14px;
}
rect {
  cursor: pointer; 
  stroke-width: 2;
}
rect.disabled {
  fill: transparent !important;
}

/* chart */
#chart {
  height: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 800px; 
}

/* tooltip */
.tooltip {
  background: #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999999;
  color: #333;
  display: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  left: 130px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 95px;
  width: 80px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.footer {
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>D3.js Donut Chart</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

      <div class="title-holder">
       <h1 class="title">2016 Average Wedding Budget Breakdown</h1>
        <p class="font">Uncheck categories to recalculate.</p>
        <p class="font new-total-holder">New Total:</p>
      </div>

      <div id="chart"></div>

      <footer>
        <a href="https://xogroupinc.com/press-releases/theknot2016realweddings_costofweddingsus/?__hstc=131446032.9fd6826aa789a27bcd4899793f171195.1518035170660.1518035170660.1518035170660.1&__hssc=131446032.1.1518035170660&__hsfp=2080303699" target="_blank">Data Source</a></li>
      </footer>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.11.0/d3.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.11.0/d3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script> <!-- remove if no javascript -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach to do that:

As you're toggling the `enabled` flag based on legend click, the new **count** can be calculated based on this flag as follows:

```
var newTotalCalc = d3.sum(dataset.filter(function(d) { return d.enabled;}), d => d.count)
```

Other minor changes:

1. You missed the dot operator here:

   ```
   var newTotal = d3.select('.new-total-holder')
   ```
2. Instead of adding another `text` element in the new total `<span>`, I'm just changing the text.

   ```
   newTotal.text(newTotalCalc);
   ```

Using the above, here's a code snippet:

```js
// define data
var dataset = [
    {label: "Venue", count: 16107},
    {label: "Photographer", count: 2783},
    {label: "Wedding/Event Planner", count: 2037},
    {label: "Reception Band", count: 4156},
    {label: "Reception DJ", count: 1245},
    {label: "Florist/Decor", count: 2534},
    {label: "Videographer", count: 1995},
    {label: "Wedding Dress", count: 1564},
    {label: "Groom's Attire", count: 280},
    {label: "Wedding Cake", count: 582},
    {label: "Ceremony Site", count: 2197},
    {label: "Ceremony Musicians", count: 755},
    {label: "Invitations", count: 2534},
    {label: "Transportation", count: 1995},
    {label: "Favors", count: 1564},
    {label: "Rehearsal Dinner", count: 280},
    {label: "Engagement Ring", count: 582},
    {label: "Officiant", count: 2197}
  ];

// chart dimensions
var width = 800;
var height = 800;

// a circle chart needs a radius
var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
var donutWidth = 100; // size of donut hole. not needed if doing pie chart

// legend dimensions
var legendRectSize = 25; // defines the size of the colored squares in legend
var legendSpacing = 6; // defines spacing between squares

// define color scale
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20b);
// more color scales: https://bl.ocks.org/pstuffa/3393ff2711a53975040077b7453781a9

// calculate new total
var total = d3.sum(dataset, d => d.count);

// define new total section
var newTotal = d3.select('.new-total-holder')
  .append('span')
  .attr('class', 'newTotal').text(total);

var svg = d3.select('#chart') // select element in the DOM with id 'chart'
  .append('svg') // append an svg element to the element we've selected
  .attr('width', width) // set the width of the svg element we just added
  .attr('height', height) // set the height of the svg element we just added
  .append('g') // append 'g' element to the svg element
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2) + ',' + (height / 2) + ')'); // our reference is now to the 'g' element. centerting the 'g' element to the svg element

var arc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius - donutWidth) // radius - donutWidth = size of donut hole. use 0 for pie chart
  .outerRadius(radius); // size of overall chart

var pie = d3.pie() // start and end angles of the segments
  .value(function(d) { return d.count; }) // how to extract the numerical data from each entry in our dataset
  .sort(null); // by default, data sorts in oescending value. this will mess with our animation so we set it to null

// define tooltip
var tooltip = d3.select('#chart') // select element in the DOM with id 'chart'
  .append('div') // append a div element to the element we've selected                                    
  .attr('class', 'tooltip'); // add class 'tooltip' on the divs we just selected

tooltip.append('div') // add divs to the tooltip defined above                            
  .attr('class', 'label'); // add class 'label' on the selection                         

tooltip.append('div') // add divs to the tooltip defined above                     
  .attr('class', 'count'); // add class 'count' on the selection                  

tooltip.append('div') // add divs to the tooltip defined above  
  .attr('class', 'percent'); // add class 'percent' on the selection

// Confused? see below:

// <div id="chart">
//   <div class="tooltip">
//     <div class="label">
//     </div>
//     <div class="count">
//     </div>
//     <div class="percent">
//     </div>
//   </div>
// </div>

dataset.forEach(function(d) {
  d.count = +d.count; // calculate count as we iterate through the data
  d.enabled = true; // add enabled property to track which entries are checked
});

// creating the chart
var path = svg.selectAll('path') // select all path elements inside the svg. specifically the 'g' element. they don't exist yet but they will be created below
  .data(pie(dataset)) //associate dataset wit he path elements we're about to create. must pass through the pie function. it magically knows how to extract values and bakes it into the pie
  .enter() //creates placeholder nodes for each of the values
  .append('path') // replace placeholders with path elements
  .attr('d', arc) // define d attribute with arc function above
  .attr('fill', function(d) { return color(d.data.label); }) // use color scale to define fill of each label in dataset
  .each(function(d) { this._current - d; }); // creates a smooth animation for each track

// mouse event handlers are attached to path so they need to come after its definition
path.on('mouseover', function(d) {  // when mouse enters div      
 var total = d3.sum(dataset.map(function(d) { // calculate the total number of tickets in the dataset         
  return (d.enabled) ? d.count : 0; // checking to see if the entry is enabled. if it isn't, we return 0 and cause other percentages to increase                                      
  }));                                                      
 var percent = Math.round(1000 * d.data.count / total) / 10; // calculate percent
 tooltip.select('.label').html(d.data.label); // set current label           
 tooltip.select('.count').html('$' + d.data.count); // set current count            
 tooltip.select('.percent').html(percent + '%'); // set percent calculated above          
 tooltip.style('display', 'block'); // set display                     
});                                                           

path.on('mouseout', function() { // when mouse leaves div                        
  tooltip.style('display', 'none'); // hide tooltip for that element
 });

path.on('mousemove', function(d) { // when mouse moves                  
  tooltip.style('top', (d3.event.layerY + 10) + 'px') // always 10px below the cursor
    .style('left', (d3.event.layerX + 10) + 'px'); // always 10px to the right of the mouse
  });

// define legend
var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend') // selecting elements with class 'legend'
  .data(color.domain()) // refers to an array of labels from our dataset
  .enter() // creates placeholder
  .append('g') // replace placeholders with g elements
  .attr('class', 'legend') // each g is given a legend class
  .attr('transform', function(d, i) {                   
    var height = legendRectSize + legendSpacing; // height of element is the height of the colored square plus the spacing      
    var offset =  height * color.domain().length / 2; // vertical offset of the entire legend = height of a single element & half the total number of elements  
    var horz = -2 * legendRectSize; // the legend is shifted to the left to make room for the text
    var vert = i * height - offset; // the top of the element is hifted up or down from the center using the offset defiend earlier and the index of the current element 'i'               
      return 'translate(' + horz + ',' + vert + ')'; //return translation       
   });

// adding colored squares to legend
legend.append('rect') // append rectangle squares to legend                                   
  .attr('width', legendRectSize) // width of rect size is defined above                        
  .attr('height', legendRectSize) // height of rect size is defined above                      
  .style('fill', color) // each fill is passed a color
  .style('stroke', color) // each stroke is passed a color
  .on('click', function(label) {
    var rect = d3.select(this); // this refers to the colored squared just clicked
    var enabled = true; // set enabled true to default
    var totalEnabled = d3.sum(dataset.map(function(d) { // can't disable all options
      return (d.enabled) ? 1 : 0; // return 1 for each enabled entry. and summing it up
    }));
    if (rect.attr('class') === 'disabled') { // if class is disabled
      rect.attr('class', ''); // remove class disabled
    } else { // else
      if (totalEnabled < 2) return; // if less than two labels are flagged, exit
      rect.attr('class', 'disabled'); // otherwise flag the square disabled
      enabled = false; // set enabled to false
    }

    pie.value(function(d) { 
      if (d.label === label) d.enabled = enabled; // if entry label matches legend label
        return (d.enabled) ? d.count : 0; // update enabled property and return count or 0 based on the entry's status
    });

    path = path.data(pie(dataset)); // update pie with new data

    path.transition() // transition of redrawn pie
      .duration(750) // 
      .attrTween('d', function(d) { // 'd' specifies the d attribute that we'll be animating
        var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d); // this = current path element
        this._current = interpolate(0); // interpolate between current value and the new value of 'd'
        return function(t) {
          return arc(interpolate(t));
        };
      });
    
    // calculate new total
    var newTotalCalc = d3.sum(dataset.filter(function(d) { return d.enabled;}), d => d.count)
   // console.log(newTotalCalc);
  
    // append newTotalCalc to newTotal which is defined above
    newTotal.text(newTotalCalc);
  });

// adding text to legend
legend.append('text')                                    
  .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
  .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
  .text(function(d) { return d; }); // return label
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
}
.title-holder {
  text-align: center;
}
.title {
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}
.font {
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* legend */
.legend {
  font-size: 14px;
}
rect {
  cursor: pointer; 
  stroke-width: 2;
}
rect.disabled {
  fill: transparent !important;
}

/* chart */
#chart {
  height: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 800px; 
}

/* tooltip */
.tooltip {
  background: #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999999;
  color: #333;
  display: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  left: 130px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 95px;
  width: 80px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.footer {
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>D3.js Donut Chart</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

      <div class="title-holder">
       <h1 class="title">2016 Average Wedding Budget Breakdown</h1>
        <p class="font">Uncheck categories to recalculate.</p>
        <p class="font new-total-holder">New Total:</p>
      </div>

      <div id="chart"></div>

      <footer>
        <a href="https://xogroupinc.com/press-releases/theknot2016realweddings_costofweddingsus/?__hstc=131446032.9fd6826aa789a27bcd4899793f171195.1518035170660.1518035170660.1518035170660.1&__hssc=131446032.1.1518035170660&__hsfp=2080303699" target="_blank">Data Source</a></li>
      </footer>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.11.0/d3.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.11.0/d3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script> <!-- remove if no javascript -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to look at my code and offering a solution. it worked out great! do you freelance by any chance?

Comment: @lisaofalltrades Glad I could help. Nope, sorry, I don't. I got a full time in Michigan. I use/try to answer questions on SO sometimes during my free time and D3 JS is something I'm very keen on improving my skills on. :)

Comment: I actually have another question here if you'd like more practice :P https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897846/broken-legend-and-tooltip-in-zoomable-sunburst-chart-d3-js

can i properly thank you with a coffee giftcard or something?! totally helping me out at work here!

Comment: Haha. Looks like an easy one. I'll add a solution to that soon. (I'm still at work). Coffee sounds good :P. I'll be visiting San Jose soon anyway.

Comment: too nice too nice. I added a 4th questions. I'll upgrade you to lunch!